# Can I be tracked

Tags: java, network-programming

Can my ip be tracked if I use this code to download an image from the internet? If so how can I avoid being tracked?

```
try(InputStream in = new.URL("http://example.com/image.jpg").openStream())
{   
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/File/To/Save/To/image.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, Use a VPN instead.

Comment: If CSI Miami has taught me anything, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes. Use a real anonymous proxy but it is not a Java matter.

Comment: What if I use vpn and tor at the same time would make it difficult.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm going to try for the most pedantic comment on the Internet today and say, that was CSI: NY.

Comment: Using VPN doesn't need a coding change.

Comment: Btw anyone know any proxy server where you can host stuff privately? without giving away identity. Can java play around with ip addresses? As mask the ip or vpn is the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be tracked. To avoid it, route through a proxy server, VPN connection, or Tor node.

Comment: Keep in mind that your proxy server, VPN or Tor node IP address might be in the proxy database like IP2Proxy.